# How To Update Plist File?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, theos

Okay I am trying update my tweaks **bundles** to the value of the `NSMutableArray`, **valididentifiers** which is populated with the users selected app identifiers such as `com.apple.mobilesafari` if the user selected the safari app inside the preference bundle for my tweak. However I am now trying to update the plist counting the supported bundles with the code bellow, however it only detects the **Filter** key when I wish to update to the **Bundles** key. I know it is only detecting the **Filter** as a valid key by logging `bundlesplist` `allKeys` attribute, and observing in the syslog.

So my question is how do I specifically update the `Bundles` section in the plist shown bellow?

**test.plist file structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Filter</key>
        <dict>
        <key>Bundles</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.mobilesafari</string>
            <string>com.apple.springboard</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**My Code:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *bundlesplist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/test.plist"];
NSLog(@"%@", bundlesplist);
NSLog(@"%@", [bundlesplist allKeys]);

[bundlesplist setObject:valididentifiers forKey:@"Bundles"];
[bundlesplist writeToFile:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/test.plist" atomically:NO];
```

**Syslog Output For allKeys**

```
2017-07-18 20:25:28.627: (
    Filter
)
```

I am not sure if I am going about this the wrong way, or just being stupid but any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should be able to set the value just using:

```
[bundlesplist setObject:valididentifiers forKeyPath:@"Filter.Bundles"];
```

However, the `Filter` dictionary is probably immutable.

Therefore, I recommend to just do:

```
NSMutableDictionary *filter = [bundlesplist[@"Filter"] mutableCopy];
filter[@"Bundles"] = valididentifiers;
bundlesplist[@"Filter"] = filter;
```